Error Parsing Swagger UI Definition after Flask REST API Deployment on Rancher Server
I have developed a Flask REST API utilizing Flask-RESTx to create endpoints and integrated Swagger UI for documentation and testing purposes. While the setup functions flawlessly on my local development environment, issues arise post-deployment within a Docker container on my Rancher server. The specific error encountered is as follows:
Errors
Parser error on line 28
end of the stream or a document separator is expected

Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

Here is an overview of the relevant files and configurations:

main.py: Contains the Flask application setup, REST API endpoints, and Swagger UI integration using Flask-RESTx.

app.py: Utilizes Gunicorn as the WSGI HTTP server to serve the Flask application in a production environment.

swagger.json: OpenAPI specification file defining the API endpoints and data models for Swagger UI.

deployment.yaml: Kubernetes deployment configuration file used to deploy the Docker containerized Flask application.

ingress.yaml: Kubernetes Ingress configuration for routing external HTTP traffic to the deployed Flask app.

service.yaml: Kubernetes Service configuration to expose the Flask app internally within the Kubernetes cluster.


The Swagger UI endpoint is expected to be accessible at http://my-flask-application/ post-deployment, but the encountered error prevents its proper rendering.
I seek assistance from the community to understand the root cause of this post-deployment error and to identify potential resolutions or best practices. Your insights and suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and expertise.
What I Tried:
I deployed my Flask REST API, which includes Swagger UI integration, within a Docker container on my Rancher server using Kubernetes. The deployment process followed standard practices, including setting up the necessary Kubernetes resources such as deployments, services, and ingress rules.
Expectation:
Post-deployment, I expected the Swagger UI documentation to be accessible and correctly rendered at the specified endpoint (http://my-flask-application/). This endpoint should display the interactive Swagger UI interface with all API endpoints documented and testable.
Actual Result:
However, upon accessing the Swagger UI endpoint, I encountered the error detailed in my initial post:
Parser error on line 28
end of the stream or a document separator is expected

Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

This error message prevents the Swagger UI from rendering correctly, leading to an inaccessible and non-functional API documentation interface.
I have ensured that all relevant files and configurations, such as swagger.json, Kubernetes deployment configurations, and Ingress rules, are correctly set up based on best practices and documentation available.
